# image watermark using PIL in django

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

i have an application which based on image.User upload images and if it is approved by the admin then it  shows in the web page.These images are not available for those user who are not in **specific plan**.User has to buy a plan and then he/she can download those images.But we know that there is default option to save images with right click.So it will be safe to give a watermark on those images.So i have decided to give watermark using PIL.

I have found a turorial here http://www.pythoncentral.io/watermark-images-python-2x/ .But not sure how to implement it in my django app since **i am very new in python and django**.The above tutorial is for a single image.But i have several images.So how to give watermark in all of my images at a time. i am using this definition in my views.py to show images in my web page.

```
def showimage(request,template = 'base.html',page_template = 'photo/showimage.html'):
    photo_list = Photo.objects.all()
    context = {}
    context.update({
        'photo_list': photo_list,
        'page_template': page_template,
    })

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template

    return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and here is my **showimage.html** where i have rendered my images...

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{%block title%}{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
{% load endless %}
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row mt" style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:10px;">
        <ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
        {% paginate 40 photo_list %}
        {% for photo in photo_list%}
              {% if photo.approved%}
              <li><a href = "{% url 'download_image' photo.id %}">
                     <img src={{photo.photo.url}} alt = 'sample photo' /></a>
              </li>
              {%endif%}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
<p>{%show_more%}</p>
{%endblock%}
```

its not necessary to use the above given link only,you can modify my above given view using your own code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the server-side url of image as: Photo.image_url

You can use the following view function to return an watermarked image:

```
from PIL import Image
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def render_image_with_watermark(request, pk, text):

    # pk is the primary key of photo model
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, pk=pk)

    # watermark the photo and save it to a temp file
    tmp_name = tempfile.mktemp()

    # this function was introduced in:
    # http://www.pythoncentral.io/watermark-images-python-2x/
    add_watermark(photo.image_url, text, out_file=tmp_name, angle=23, opacity=0.25)

    # render the watermarked photo to response
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(photo.image_url, 'rb'))
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(wrapper, 'image/jpeg')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(photo.image_url)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=photo.jpg'

    return response
```

In case you want to render all images with watermarked, you can first make the render_image_with_watermark view above has a url:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^photo/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'render_image_with_watermark', name='render_image_with_watermark'),
    ...
)
```

After doing this, try to visit the url /photo/**photo.pk**，if success, it will render the image directly.

Then, change your showimage.html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{%block title%}{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
{% load endless %}
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row mt" style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:10px;">
        <ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
        {% paginate 40 photo_list %}
        {% for photo in photo_list%}
              {% if photo.approved%}
              <li><a href = "{% url 'download_image' photo.id %}">


                     <!-- ATTENTION HERE -->
                     <img src={% url 'render_image_with_watermark' pk=photo.id %} alt = 'sample photo' /></a>

              </li>
              {%endif%}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
<p>{%show_more%}</p>
{%endblock%}
```

Have a try.

Comment: i have tried your above code.. now there is no images are showing,only the alternative image icons are showing.

Comment: Does the photo.image_url pointed to the original image path on the server-side correctly?  @user2971215

Comment: may be not.. this is the also be another issue,infact i don't know how to set it or what should be the url,i am sorry , i am really new in python and django

Comment: First you should try the url I suggest. Did you see the watermarked photo rendered correctly then? Until so, debug with your html template.

Comment: i have used 'photo.image_url'.. then its not working,then i tried 'photo.url'.. it also not working

Comment: infact these images are stored in database

Comment: so these images are fetching from the database,so what should be the image url for photo.image_url?

Comment: The render_image_with_watermark view just write image filestream to the http response, if your image was stored in database, you can also change the code to get the filestream.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [watermark tutorial](http://www.pythoncentral.io/author/alvin-khoo/)

**Additional info**: For website output, here are the changes:-

```
 import os, sys, StringIO ## change line 2 ##

 def add_watermark(in_file, angle=23, opacity=0.25): ## change line 6 ##
     out_file = StringIO.StringIO() ## insert after line 6 ##
     ...
     return out_file.getValue() ## insert after 24 ##
```

To use it:  `myImage = add_watermark(photo_image)`. Create the HTTP header and output with `myImage`. Basically we're saving the JPG to StringIO and using getValue() to read it.

Also check Mark's fork which [overlays an image](https://gist.github.com/makmac213/a4ab09f5a042c5477037) instead.